# Salesforce - trailhead Generate and Analyze Logs challenge issue

Tags: salesforce

I followed their steps to execute a log:
[image]

and I get this message!?
[image]

why is this not working?

**And please note i did not put 'my email@gmail.com' but my actual email.**